# Getting all files under a folder and subfolders in a recursive manner, without the path of the subfolders itself

Tags: python, file, path

I want to list all the full path of the files under a folder and all its subfolders recursively. Is there a way to do it? It seems that if the files go into 2 levels, the code can be written like is,

```
import os


folderPATH = r'C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\Cosmology\Articles'
filePATHS = [x[2] for x in os.walk(folderPATH)]

for i in filePATHS:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

prints

```
Astrophysical Constants And Parameters.pdf
desktop.ini
Physics Latex Manuel.pdf
Spactimes.pdf
A parametric reconstruction of the cosmological jerk from diverse observational data.pdf
A Thousand Problems in Cosmology Horizons.pdf
An Almost Isotropic CM Temperature Does Not Imply An Almost Isotropic Universe.pdf
Big Bang Cosmology - Review.pdf
desktop.ini
Expanding Confusion common misconceptions of cosmological horizons and the superluminal expansion of the universe.pdf
Hubble Radius.pdf
Is the Universe homogeneous.pdf
LCDM and Mond.pdf
Near galaxy clusters.pdf
The Cosmological Constant and Dark Energy.pdf
The mass of the Milky Way from satellite dynamic.pdf
The Status of Cosmic Topology after Planck Data.pdf
An upper limit to the central density of dark matter haloes from consistency with the presence of massive central black holes.pdf
Dark Matter - Review.pdf
Dark Matter Accretion into Supermassive Black Holes.pdf
desktop.ini
Andrew H. Jaﬀe - Cosmology - Imperial College Lecture Notes - Thermodynamics and Particle Physics.pdf
Big Bang Nucleosynthesis.pdf
Claus Grupen - Astroparticle Physics - The Early Universe.pdf
Daniel Baumann - Cosmology - Mathematical Tripos III - Thermal History.pdf
desktop.ini
James Rich - Fundamentals of Cosmology - The Thermal History of the Universe.pdf
Lars Bergström, Ariel Goobar - Cosmology and Particle Astrophysics -  Thermodynamics in the Early Universe.pdf  
Steven Weinberg - Cosmology - The Early Universe.pdf
Andrei Linde - On the problem of initial conditions for inﬂation.pdf
...
```

I want a function that produces the same results **but with recursive logic and with the full paths**. So that for `n` nested folders, I can find the paths. I need something like this,

```
import os

def get_all_filePATHs(folderPATH):
    ...
    return get_all_filePATHs()

folderPATH = r'C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\Cosmology\Articles'
print(get_all_filePATHs(folderPATH))
```

Note that I am only interested in the **full path of the files and not the path of the subfolders**, as you can see from the example above.

Comment: `os.walk()` recurses into all subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk()` recurses into all subdirectories. The first element returned in each iteration is the path to the directory, you join that with the filename to get the full path of the file.

```
def get_all_filePaths(folderPath):
    result = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folderPath):
        result.extend([os.path.join(dirpath, filename) for filename in filenames])
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```py
from pathlib import Path
# set main directory
folderPATH=Path('Оплата')
# loop over subdirs and files
print([Path(folderPATH.resolve().parent, the_path) for the_path in folderPATH.rglob("*")])
```